# Swift 2.0 - Google Analytics Event builder error - NSMutableDictionary is not convertible to [NSObject : AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

**Worked perfectly on Swift 1.2**

code :

```
 var build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("Record Counter", action: "Images Taken", label: "usersad", value: 1  ).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
 self.tracker.send(build)
```

Error :

```
NSMutableDictionary is not convertible to [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Since it is a objective C dictionary, you don't need to perform any typecasting. When you bridge from an NSDictionary object to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type [NSObject: AnyObject]

Comment: i tried delete the casting but it shows me the same error . so what should i do?

Comment: @Shripada see my comment above please

Comment: @Shripada Can you please exapand?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're casting your event wrong. Here is the correct way and one way of doing it.

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
```

Initialize your Event Tracker as NSObject

```
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(
                "ui_action",
                action: "button_press",
                label: "play",
                value: nil).build()
```

Cast your NSObject as Anyobject within the send method.

```
tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: Thanks LGL!  :) u r awesome

Comment: should that last line be:  tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])